# Should each NFT have a separate smart contract

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, cryptocurrency, nft

I want to create an NFT with 6 different variations. Besides the similar artwork, they're gonna share some custom capabilities.

My question is, what is the more efficient approach, and are there any drawbacks to using the same Smart Contract?

Answer (score 0):

A common practice is to group tokens of similar meaning in a collection.

Widely used standards are:

- [ERC721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) for collection of unique items - for example drawings
- [ERC1155](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155) for collection of items that can have multiple copies - such as hockey player cards

Based on the description in your question, you might want to mint 6 tokens (one for each variation) in the ERC721 collection.

Comment: To clarify further, is it correct to say:  ERC721 - The paintings of Picasso  ERC1155 - Hockey Player Card where you can have 2 or more of the same Jaromir Jager rookie cards.